# BizTalk testing maps with multiple input xml or is it Inline C# that is the problem?

Tags: unit-testing, dictionary, biztalk

Can anyone explain how to get unit tests of BizTalk maps with multiple inputs to work?

I've been happily using the examples on Michael Stephenson [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20201125031253/http://geekswithblogs.net/michaelstephenson/archive/2008/03/30/120851.aspx) to test my maps, but I've just tried my first multiple input map and it's failing  :-(

I've used the VS2005 "Test Map" to first generate an input instance with the two input messages, then used varieties of that file as test inputs ...

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema">
  <InputMessagePart_0>
    ...
  </InputMessagePart_0>
  <InputMessagePart_1>
    ...
  </InputMessagePart_1>
</ns0:Root>
```

These test messages generate the expected output when I use the VS Test Map, but a section is missing when I try the unit tests.

The only thing I can think of is the map has some functoids in ... *Scripting, Table Extractor and Table Looping* ...

The unit test calls the StreamingTransform.ScalableTransform ...

```
// This is the BizTalk Server 2006 way of calling 
mapInstance.StreamingTransform.Transform(inputStream, 
    mapInstance.TransformArgs, outputStream, resolver);
// This is the R2 way of calling
XmlReader xmlRdr = new XmlTextReader(inputStream);
mapInstance.StreamingTransform.ScalableTransform(xmlRdr, 
    mapInstance.TransformArgs, outputStream, 
    resolver, whitespaceCorrect);
```

and the alternative approach of using the Transform.Transform doesn't work either ...

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(inputStream);
mapInstance.Transform.Transform(doc, mapInstance.TransformArgs, outputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
mapInstance.Transform.Transform(
   multi-part input message filepath, out put file path);
```

It works for me. I have declared `mapInstance` as an object of the `Map` class (not declared it as `TestableMapBase`).